# Why was my suggested edit to remove irrelevant stuff rejected?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

I suggested an edit to [this question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/origins-of-proof-in-mathematics), in order to remove what I considered to be irrelevant meta-commentary:

> I recently asked this question on [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323572/why-are-we-always-concerned-with-showing-and-proofs-in-math) however, I, now, like many others believe that it would be more appropriate to post it here. Thanks in advance.

with the comment:

> removed meta-commentary (the link to Math SE was dead in any case) and "thanks in advance"

Nevertheless, my edit was rejected by the OP.

Why was this so? What does such a comment (with a dead link) about what the OP "and many others believe" (now...) or not add to the question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out to me, I was unaware of the reason why it was better not to add things like that to my post but now I understand and am aware of these guidelines. I have fixed my posts across all stack exchange sites.